# Angularjs: Ng-Model and Ng-Change giving undefined in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown that is defined using angular's ng-options syntax.  I also have ng-model on the element and I am trying to get the selected model to output to the console.  I have read a lot of different SO questions, but I just keep getting undefined.  When I have the model defined in a service on rootScope then I get null.

Not sure what is going on, but it seems like the object isn't getting into the ng-model.

In the view:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-change="updateCategory()" 
ng-options="conference.Name for conference in Adminconferences 
| orderBy:['Name'] "></select>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.updateCategory = function () {
    console.log($scope.selected);
}
```

Update: I realized that maybe if i include what i am trying to do then maybe I can get better responses and have a better question.

This dropdown list is located in the header of my site.  I want the user to be able to select which conference they want to manage. Based on that, I want all of the data in the site to be based on the conference's Id. I am not sure what the angular way of doing this is. I think i need to use rootScope and just reference it whenever i need the id for data calls.  Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialize $scope.selected in the controller before you use it inside function.
Initialize it like this:

```
$scope.selected = 0;
```

and then use it inside the function.